# Android4.0.3 source code build errors : [out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libext_intermediates/initext.o] Error 1

Tags: java, android, linux, ubuntu-14.04

ENV : Ubuntu 14

```
STATIC_LIBRARIES/libext_intermediates/initext.c:9: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '-' token
out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libext_intermediates/initext.c:9:28: error: invalid suffix "_init" on integer constant
out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libext_intermediates/initext.c:16: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '-' token
out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libext_intermediates/initext.c:16:24: error: invalid suffix "_init" on integer constant
out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libext_intermediates/initext.c:27: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '-' token
out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libext_intermediates/initext.c:27:24: error: invalid suffix "_init" on integer constant
out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libext_intermediates/initext.c:40: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '-' token
out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libext_intermediates/initext.c:40:27: error: invalid suffix "_init" on integer constant
out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libext_intermediates/initext.c:45: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '-' token
out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libext_intermediates/initext.c:45:23: error: invalid suffix "_init" on integer constant
out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libext_intermediates/initext.c:53: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '-' token
out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libext_intermediates/initext.c:53:26: error: invalid suffix "_init" on integer constant
out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libext_intermediates/initext.c:57: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '-' token
out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libext_intermediates/initext.c:57:23: error: invalid suffix "_init" on integer constant
out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libext_intermediates/initext.c: In function 'init_extensions':
out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libext_intermediates/initext.c:73: error: 'libxt_CONNMARK' undeclared (first use in this function)
out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libext_intermediates/initext.c:73: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libext_intermediates/initext.c:73: error: for each function it appears in.)
out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libext_intermediates/initext.c:73:17: error: invalid suffix "_init" on integer constant
out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libext_intermediates/initext.c:80: error: 'libxt_DSCP' undeclared (first use in this function)
out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libext_intermediates/initext.c:80:13: error: invalid suffix "_init" on integer constant
out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libext_intermediates/initext.c:91: error: 'libxt_MARK' undeclared (first use in this function)
out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libext_intermediates/initext.c:91:13: error: invalid suffix "_init" on integer constant
out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libext_intermediates/initext.c:104: error: 'libxt_rateest' undeclared (first use in this function)
out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libext_intermediates/initext.c:104:16: error: invalid suffix "_init" on integer constant
out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libext_intermediates/initext.c:109: error: 'libxt_SET' undeclared (first use in this function)
out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libext_intermediates/initext.c:109:12: error: invalid suffix "_init" on integer constant
out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libext_intermediates/initext.c:117: error: 'libxt_TCPMSS' undeclared (first use in this function)
out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libext_intermediates/initext.c:117:15: error: invalid suffix "_init" on integer constant
out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libext_intermediates/initext.c:121: error: 'libxt_TOS' undeclared (first use in this function)
out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libext_intermediates/initext.c:121:12: error: invalid suffix "_init" on integer constant
make: *** [out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libext_intermediates/initext.o] Error 1
```

Comment: The reason is : I  unzip the code in MAC , then upload the code to linux.  just  unzip the source code in Linux I fix  the problem

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as well, but find nothing in googling. Fortunately, I finally find the answer.

**Solution:**
Rename every .c/.h file that end with -1, to its original name (delete -1) in directory external/iptables/extensions and extenal/iptables/include/linux/netfilter

**Cause:**
This issue is quite corner one. I download a "packed" Android source code without .repo from Internet instead of painfully checking out from google. It is the source code package that cause the error. The source code was checked out to a case-insensitive filesystem, so "duplicated" filename which only differ by capital was renamed by git. For example, there is a xt_mark.h and a xt_MARK.h in the same directory. Git automatically rename the latter file to xt-MARTK-1.h to avoid overwritten, on a case insensitive filesystem.

The external/iptables/extension/libext project, there are many files such as

```
 libxt_set.c
 libxt_SET.c    => libxt_SET-1.c
 libxt_dscp.c
 libxt_DSCP.c   => libxt_DSCP-1.c
```

....

These duplicated file name that just with difference in case.
It may work in most case, but the project's makefile enumerate every c file with libxt_xxx.c format and generate a init .c file for all them. So in the generated inittext.c, function entries like:

```
libxt_DSCP-1_init();
libxt_SET-1_init();
```

were generated. '-' was forbidden in function/variable name.